# WebSockets with Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, websocket

I am new to the Websocket world. I have implemented 2 API's one for getting the comments and one for posting the comments to a post. Using the following technologies.

1. Laravel 5.7
2. http://socketo.me/
3. Vue + Echo
4. Following https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLwAKR305CRO9rlj-U9oOi4m2sQaWN6XA8

The above WebSockets are working fine with browser to browser in Axios calls, my question is how can I write WebSockets for Android/iOS developers and test like we do for API's and use postman for testing.

I have looked into iOS developer code they were using something like **ws://123.123.123.123/socket** Please guide how can I convert my WebSockets as ws: and deploy to stage server?

How to make a WebSocket on the above-mentioned technologies that iOS/Android developers can use directly?

I am sure my question looks basic, guidance can change it :-)

I want to send coordinates(lat,lng) from one device to another device as the location of the rider. If I am not wrong one device will push and another device will listen?
How can I write those WebSockets calls?

Comment: Your **W**eb**S**ockets are already sent through WS protocol, your question is unclear

Comment: Yes my question is exactly this one, how can I develop ws protocol WebSocket calls, in my example, I am hitting ajax HTTP calls for WebSockets.

Comment: WebSocket calls should be dispatched from the backend, clients only **listen** to changes pushed